# Tag merge request: bitwise operations

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

I think the following tags should be considered as synonyms (or perhaps for merging) under [bitwise-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-operators):

[bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift)  [bit-shift-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift-operators)  [bitwise-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-and)  [bitwise-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-or)  [bitwise-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-shift)  [bitwise-xor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-xor)

I don't really see what positive effect breaking the operations out will have; it makes tagging a bear, and makes finding related questions difficult. Thoughts?

Comment: No "bitwise-not", not even as an alias for [tag:ones-complement]?

Comment: Not that I can see. Odd.

Comment: There are issues with doing bit-shifting on signed values in C and C++, as an example. Remove signedness or use another bit-op, and they disappear. So, no. Also, I wonder why you don't want to put them under [tag:bit-manipulation] if you want to merge/synonymize.

Comment: They're still bitwise operations. [tag:bit-shift] doesn't explicitly involve C++, so why should we let C++ concerns break the [tag:bitwise-operators] tag out to this degree? We have a tag for C++ concerns: [tag:C++]. I assumed that [tag:bit-manipulation] was more of a bit twiddling thing - related to ops, but not directly.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you mean @Deduplicator - didn't notice that [tag:bitwise] was already synonymous with [tag:bit-manipulation]. Removing it from my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Not all of those are synonyms, so they shouldn't all be merged. You have three different groups.

1. [bitwise-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-operators) should probably be a synonym of [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation). ([bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise) already is a synonym of [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation).)
2. [bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift), [bit-shift-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift-operators), and [bitwise-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-shift) all mean the same thing, so they should be merged.
3. [bitwise-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-and), [bitwise-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-or), and [bitwise-xor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitwise-xor) all mean different things. They're more specific than the tags in #1, so they should not be merged.

Comment: Noted the synonym for [tag:bitwise] after Deduplicator pointed it out - removed it as a suggestion, since it doesn't fit the tags proposed for merging well. Completely agree with #2. #3 is more a matter of opinion - I personally feel like the tags are overly specific.

Comment: @Conduit I'm sure some people think bit-manipulation isn't specific enough. That's why you can put five tags on a question.

Comment: Hah, I suppose that's true - I prefer succinctness, myself, but that's not for everyone. Merging the "shift" tags is still a good plan regardless.

Comment: @Conduit: Now if we had tag-hierarchies... Well, it works acceptable without.